# Highest integer in the list

Tags: python

Suppose we have `[4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6]` how do I get the 3 highest in descending order without using `.sort` or `sorted()`

I was thinking that we can use

```
x = [4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6]
mad(x) = 6
y = x.remove(max(x)) #[4, 5, 2, 3, 1]
```

Then continue to get a `max(y) = 5`. Until we finally get `[6,5,4]`  How do I write this function ?

Comment: What's wrong with using ```sorted()```?

Comment: Nothing wrong just looking for another way to write this function

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest), like this

```
from heapq import nlargest
print nlargest(3, [4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 6])
# [6, 5, 4]
```

Comment: Is there anyway that we can write it recursively with what I suggested ?